# SMS failure in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I have sent an outbound SMS to an audience of 1000 by data extension but in the overview tab in MobileConnect, it is showing me only 2500 messages are delivered. also status is shown as complete. where can I see what happened with other audiences? What error has occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be related to many reasons.

Check if phone numbers are valid on all records on your audience data extension. Note that:

> You can send only to data extensions that are marked as sendable and
>   that contain one phone field and one locale field. Mobile numbers used
>   in the data extension must be normalized during the imports process.

It also depends on the option that you have selected for the send (cf image below).

If you chosed the first option, then all contacts need to be subscribed to at least one keyword to receive the SMS.

If you chosed the second option, then you have two use cases:

**Use case 1:** If the contact has been attached to this keyword in AllContacts, then SFMC will respect the consent. The contact will only receive the SMS if he's opted in. In case he's Opted out from this keyword, he will not receive the SMS and will not be re-opted in.

**Use case 2:** If the contact has not been attached to this keyword on AllContacts, he will receive the SMS and will be Opted-in to the keyword.

[image]

You can query `_UndeliverableSms` data view and join it to your audience Data Extension to get the delivery status of your SMS.

The problem can also be related to other reasons like:

> Messages fail to reach the device for a few reasons, such as:
>
> mobile device is powered off user is out of range of cellular networks
>   number is for a landline causes not related to Marketing Cloud

You can run this query on Query Studio to get information about undelivered SMS messages:

```
SELECT mobilenumber, Undeliverable, BounceCount, FirstBounceDate, HoldDate FROM _UndeliverableSms
```

References:

- [Data View: Undeliverable SMS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_undeliverable_sms.htm&type=5)
- [Review Undelivered Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_retrieving_information_on_undelivered_sms_messages_for_mobileconnect.htm&type=5)

Comment: thank you for your response! if i am sending sms for the first time to the audience will they get automatically added to all contacts

Comment: i did not any of the audience to all contacts then how came 2500 audience got the message? I checked also if they are present in all contacts and yes they are there

Comment: Update: contatcs will be added automatically to AllContacts - Mobile list if you chose to subscribe them to a keyword. That explains why the 2500 received your message even if you did not import them..